# Wiring A Rotary Switch To Provide Custom Functionality

Tags: switches

I am resubmitting part of a previous question to try to make it more relevant as the original ended up being considered off topic and closed. A couple of folks have seen the original question and even provided some ideas. However, I don't have a very deep knowledge of electronics, so I need a bit more guidance.

I am trying to replace a switch whose manufacturer states has the following function: OFF, 1-2-4, 1-2-3, 1-3-4. The switch is a 4-position rotary switch with a square body and 4 connection pins at the bottom labeled 1, 2, 3 and 4. However, only 3 pins (1, 3 and 4) are being used. The manufacturer does not specify anything about the number of poles, and I don't know if that means single pole.

user253751 suggested I could use another 4 position switch with 1 or 2 poles and wire it with the help of jumpers in a way that could provide the original switch functionality.

I am open to doing that; however, I don't know how to read 1-2-4, 1-2-3 and 1-3-4. What does that mean? Is that continuity between the connection pins at the bottom of the switch? I tried to draw those connections, but in my drawing everything seems to be connected to everything. Do I need something with multiple poles and/or more connection pins?

Could any of you guys shed some more light on what I could do please?

Thanks,

Update: This image shows the bottom of the switch!

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you should first verify what the switch is actually doing.  See if the terminals are marked, and see if none are connected when OFF, 1-2-4 are all connected in the first position, etc.

Comment: @rdtsc, The switch has a square body  and the four terminals are marked with the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4. I will follow your advice regarding trying to figure out what the switch is doing and see what I can find out.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement 2-pole, 4-position rotary switch is to be wired as shown

shown, in order to satisfy the switching requirements.

Position 'a' : Off

Position 'b' : 1-2-4

Position 'c' : 1-2-3

Position 'd' : 1-3-4

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I do appreciate your taking the time to put that diagram together. It helps me quite a lot to understand what I need to look for!

Comment: You are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a single pole triple throw switch with pin 1 being the pole and arranged to have four positions:

- A) Off - Pin 1 not connected to any of the throws
- B) 1-2-4 - Pin 1 connected to pins 2 and 4
- C) 1-2-3 - Pin 1 connected to pins 2 and 3
- D) 1-3-4 - Pin 1 connected to pins 3 and 4

This would allow pin 1 to be connected to one side of the AC line and switch power to three different loads where in each position two of the loads would be powered. How this is done internally is hard to say without disassembling the switch.

To mimic this behavior with a standard rotary switch you would need a 3P4T switch. Each deck would have it's pole connected to what would be pin 1 on the existing switch, then the poles of one deck would be connected to pin 2 in positions B and C, one would connect to pin 3 in positions C and D, and the third would connect pin 4 in positions B and D.

Since you say one pin was not connected you would probably only need a 2P4T switch, leaving out the deck for whichever pin is not used.

Comment: Thank you so much, @GodJihyo! I cannot thank you enough for sharing that explanation with me. I will  looking into what you suggested and see about buying the type of switch you recommend and give it a try!